# Getting the error when I am trying to connect the on prem IBM DB2 from Azure using Microsoft integration runtime

Tags: azure, db2

We are trying to get the data from On Premise IBM DB2 from Azure Data Factory using Microsoft Integration Runtime. We are able to connect the database also we are able to get the list of tables in the ADF Dataset but when we are trying to execute the query we are getting the below error. Not able to identify the issue. Help me on this.

> ROUTINE SQLSTATISTICS (SPECIFIC NAME SQLSTATISTICS) HAS RETURNED AN
>   ERROR SQLSTATE WITH DIAGNOSTIC TEXT -805
>   DSN.DSNASPCC.DSNASTAU.0E5F1F1D09F1404 SQLSTATE=38112 SQLCODE=-443

[Error Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHu15.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you follow this [technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21449630) to bind db2schema.bnd to the target Db2 database, after ensuring your Db2 client has the same version/fixpack as the Db2-server.